# Need help writing file to external storage

Tags: java, android, file, io

I've been searching the internet for several hours now in an attempt to find a file writing function that actually works for me.  So far I have this in my MainActivity.java:

```
public void writeToFile(String data, Context ctx) {
    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    File tempFile = new File(path, "houseDataFile.txt");
    if(!tempFile.exists()){
        tempFile.mkdirs();
    }
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        fOut.write(data.getBytes());
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "FileOutputStream exception: - " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

My android manifest contains both permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="my.package.application"xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Menu_activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Though rather frustratingly when I run the app and call writeToFile() it gives me an error saying:

```
W/MainActivity: FileOutputStream exception: - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/houseDataFile.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Does `/storage/emulated/0/Documents` exist?

Comment: Is your device's android version is >=  6.x.x (Marsh Mallow) ?

Comment: `been searching the internet for several hours now`. If you had read some stackoverflow pages tagged android you would have found your problem reported several times. Several times each week.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are failing to get the file path because you don't asking runtime-permission while executing method. Here you can take a look at the below code.

First, check if your device's OS version is above Lollipop or not. If above then show permission pop-up dialog.

```
final int MyVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (MyVersion > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
{
    if (!checkIfAlreadyhavePermission())
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ProfileActivity.this, new String[] {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        writeToFile(data, ctx);
    }
}
else
{
    writeToFile(data, ctx)
}

 private boolean checkIfAlreadyhavePermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

Then define "Allow" and "Deny" button functionalities in OnRequestPerMissionResult().

```
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    writeToFile( data, ctx);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Please provide permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
    }
```

Please let me know if this solves the issue.

Comment: Now I am receiving error: `FileOutputStream exception: - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/houseDataFile.txt: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)`.  I'm going to try and write to the internal storage and see if that helps at all.

Comment: Did you try with WRITE PERMISSION too ?